# why from json response show in tableView unordered list value swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlAvo.png)import UIKit

class MyCircleViewPresenter: BaseViewPresenter {

```
typealias V = MyCircleViewDelegate
var mView: V?

func getMyCircle(url: String){
    mView?.onNetworkCallStarted("please_wait".localized())
   AlamofireService.getSession()
        .request(url, method: .get).validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            self.mView?.onNetworkCallEnded()
            switch(response.result){
            case .success(_):
                guard let decodedObj = response.decode(objectType: MyCircleResponse.self) else {
                    self.mView?.myCircleDidReceived(response: nil)
                    return
                }
                self.mView?.myCircleDidReceived(response: decodedObj)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                self.mView?.handleError(httpSatusCode: response.response?.statusCode, errorData: response.data, error: error)
                break
            }
        }
}
```

}

//
//  MyCircleViewController.swift

import UIKit

struct MyCircleSection {

```
let number: String
let recharges: [SingeRecharge]
var isOpened: Bool = false

struct SingeRecharge {
    let amount: String
    let rechargeType: Int
    let create_at: String
}
```

}

class MyCircleViewController: BaseViewController {

```
// Out let >>>>>
@IBOutlet weak var card_current_month: CardView!
@IBOutlet weak var card_last_3o_days: CardView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var lb_my_circle_total: RegularLabel!

var sections = [MyCircleSection]()
var mPresenter = MyCircleViewPresenter()

var historyType = Constants.HistoryType.CURRENT_MONTH

override func onViewDidLoaded() {
    mPresenter.setViewDelegate(mView: self)
    
    // Set Up table View
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 62
    
    // Swipe
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    
    setupClickListener()
    
    card_current_month.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.PRIMARY)!
    card_last_3o_days.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
    card_current_month.shadowColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
    card_last_3o_days.shadowColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(menuDidTapped), name: .MENU_DID_TAPPED, object: nil)
    if(historyType == Constants.HistoryType.CURRENT_MONTH){ // Curent Month
        card_current_month.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.PRIMARY)!
        card_last_3o_days.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
        mPresenter.getMyCircle(url: APIs.MY_CIRCLE + "/\(historyType)")
    }else{ // Last 30 days
        card_current_month.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
        card_last_3o_days.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.PRIMARY)!
        mPresenter.getMyCircle(url: APIs.MY_CIRCLE + "/\(historyType)")
       
    }
    lb_my_circle_total.text = "..."
    tableView.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .MENU_DID_TAPPED, object: nil)
}



@objc func menuDidTapped(_ notification: NSNotification){
    guard let menuType = notification.object as? MenuType else {
        return
    }
    print("Menu Type: Reward >>> \(menuType)")
    switch menuType {
    case .PROFILE:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: ProfileViewController.className, sender: self)
        break
        
    case .REFER_SC_APP:
        AppUtils.shared.referThisApp(fromVc: self)
        break
    case .TRANSACTION_AND_STATEMENT:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: TransactionViewController.className, sender: self)
        break
    case .FAQ:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: FaqViewController.className, sender: self)
        break
    case .SUPPORT:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: SupportViewController.className, sender: self)
        break
    case .SETTINGS:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: SettingsViewController.className, sender: self)
        break
    case .LOGOUT:
        showLogoutDialog()
        break
    }
}


func setupClickListener(){
    card_current_month.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tabClickListener(_:))))
    card_last_3o_days.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tabClickListener(_:))))
}

@objc func tabClickListener(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
    guard let tag = gesture.view?.tag else { return }
    if(tag == 1){ // Curent Month
        if(historyType != Constants.HistoryType.CURRENT_MONTH){
            historyType = Constants.HistoryType.CURRENT_MONTH
            lb_my_circle_total.text = "..."
            tableView.isHidden = true
            
            card_current_month.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.PRIMARY)!
            card_last_3o_days.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
            mPresenter.getMyCircle(url: APIs.MY_CIRCLE + "/\(Constants.HistoryType.CURRENT_MONTH)")
        }
     
    }else{ // Last 30 days
        if(historyType != Constants.HistoryType.LAST_30_DAYS){
            historyType = Constants.HistoryType.LAST_30_DAYS
            lb_my_circle_total.text = "..."
            tableView.isHidden = true
            
            card_current_month.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.GREY_LIGHT)!
            card_last_3o_days.borderColor = UIColor(hexaRGB: Color.PRIMARY)!
            mPresenter.getMyCircle(url: APIs.MY_CIRCLE + "/\(Constants.HistoryType.LAST_30_DAYS)")
        }
      
    }

}


@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .USER_DID_SWIPE_TO_LEFT, object: nil)
    }
}
```

}

extension MyCircleViewController: MyCircleViewDelegate {

```
func myCircleDidReceived(response: MyCircleResponse?) {
    if(response == nil){
        lb_my_circle_total.text = "0"
        showErrorDialog(title: "No data found!", msg: nil, titleFullRed: true)
    }else{
        lb_my_circle_total.text = "\(response!.data.count)"
        // Format Data for Table View >>>
        if (!sections.isEmpty) {sections.removeAll()}
        for (number , recharges) in response!.data {
            var rechargeHistories = [MyCircleSection.SingeRecharge]()
            for singleRecharge in recharges {
                rechargeHistories.append(MyCircleSection.SingeRecharge(amount: singleRecharge.amount, rechargeType : singleRecharge.rechargeType, create_at: singleRecharge.createdAt))
            }
            sections.append(MyCircleSection(number: number, recharges: rechargeHistories))
        }
        // Reload Table view data >>>
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

}

//// Table View Delegate >>>
extension MyCircleViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]
    return section.isOpened ? section.recharges.count + 1 : 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        guard  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCircleHeaderCell.className) as? MyCircleHeaderCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        cell.lb_circle_number.text = section.recharges.isEmpty ? section.number : section.number + " (\(section.recharges.count))"
        cell.img_arrow.image = section.isOpened ? UIImage(named: "ic-arrow-up") : UIImage(named: "ic-down-arrow")
        return cell
    }else{
        guard  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCircleRowCell.className) as? MyCircleRowCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        let data = sections[indexPath.section].recharges[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.lb_amount.text = Constants.TAKA_UNICODE + "\(data.amount)"
        let formattedDateTime = DateUtils.shared.convertUTCtimeToLocale(dateToFormat: data.create_at)
        cell.lb_date.text = formattedDateTime.0
        cell.lb_time.text = formattedDateTime.1
        switch "\(data.rechargeType)" {
        case Constants.RechargeType.EASY_LOAD:
            cell.lb_type.text = "Easyload"
        case Constants.RechargeType.BUNDLE:
            cell.lb_type.text = "Bundle"
        case Constants.RechargeType.INTERNET:
            cell.lb_type.text = "Internet"
        case Constants.RechargeType.VOICE:
            cell.lb_type.text = "Voice"
        case Constants.RechargeType.VAS:
            cell.lb_type.text = "Vas"
        default:
            cell.lb_type.text = ""
            break
        }
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
        tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
    }
}
```

}

// Qeustion Cell >>>>
class MyCircleHeaderCell: UITableViewCell{

```
@IBOutlet weak var lb_circle_number : RegularLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var img_arrow: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.selectionStyle = .none
}
```

}

// Answer Cell >>>
class MyCircleRowCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var lb_date : PreRegularLight!
@IBOutlet weak var lb_time : PreRegularLight!
@IBOutlet weak var lb_amount: PreRegularBoldLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lb_type: PreRegularLight!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.selectionStyle = .none
}
```

}

Comment: There are plenty of useless code that make it hard to understand... What's your JSON look like? You decode your API as it's given. But what's the order of the API? Either it has an available "sort" parameter in the request you can use, or you sort yourself the answer according to the order you want. "Should we guess what's the order logic"? And I mean "we" as the program itself", would it be ascending date? descending date? You see, why should one ordre prevail the other? You need to code the sorting.

Answer (score 2):

a JSON response is never sorted in some way. it always come in different orders, and are decoded as such. i suggest you yourself sort the array on date or something to get a consistent order of the objects.